# Animated science fiction movie where a protagonist has a glowing round map on his hand

Tags: story-identification, animation

Please help me remember the name of an animated sci-fi movie from the 80s or 90s. I know that it was about a guy who had some sort of round, orange-glowing map on his hand. The action took place in space and it also had something to do with a ring from his father, who had died years ago but left him a message on a certain spaceship. And that's kinda all I remember.
Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: Shame the answer has nearly 3 times more votes than the answer. I'll never understand why people neglect the question itself.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Titan A.E.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120913/?ref_=ttmi_tt) fits the description, except it was released in 2000. The plot synopsis presented in the linked IMDB entry mentions a ring passed down from the protagonist's father and the search for the ship "Titan". And there's an orange map:

[image: Image showing orange map on hand]
[Image Source: toonzone.net](http://www.toonzone.net/news/images/2010-06/titanae/titanae02.jpg)

Comment: Thank you very much! (I wasn't very sure about the date..), but thanks anyway

Comment: http://25.media.tumblr.com/403d137404dfda2e361bebd7ede9a757/tumblr_mr8d1ehKLs1s04jy3o6_500.gif